# What are the protocols used when communicating with facebook server( login and messenger part)?

Tags: facebook, authentication, protocols, wireshark, facebook-messenger

What are the protocols used when logging in to facebook and using facebook messenger?

I read somewhere in google that the messenger uses MQTT protocol;
How can I catch and analyze its related network packets in Wireshark?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mobile application is using the MQTT protocol. The messenger on the webpage on the other hand, along with the login page communicate through a standard HTTPS protocol as the remaining part of the application.

You can sniff the HTTPS packets being sent on the local network, through wireshark but since HTTPS is SSL encrypted, you will just see hashes in the response body and you will not see the actual text. That's probably the main reason why you couldn't find it. In wireshark the HTTPS is denoted as SSLv3.

Comment: I read some documents that guide ```Decrypting with Pre-Master Secrets```, but when I search preferences -> protocol in Wireshark, it not found SSL protocol, I just found TLS protocol alternative

Comment: It should be HTTPS which is the protocol, when you submit a request on the web messenger you actually see a XHR request being fired in the dev console, I am still researching it a bit since I don't see the message content in the request payload so maybe there is something more in the background. For mobile app its MQTT. You are not trying to sniff people passwords by any chance?

Comment: I found this for MQTT if you interested: http://blog.catchpoint.com/2017/07/06/dissecting-mqtt-using-wireshark/

Comment: oh, that's great. now I understand that fb messenger in web platform using HTTPS and mobile using MQTT. Thanks for your answer very much

Comment: Happy to help @leebongee ;)

Comment: but I'm still wondering that if HTTPS is SSL encrypted so how I find which is the package of fb message when I chatting on FB? Because wireshark shows me many packages that use TCP, UDP, TLS... even I don't find any package which uses HTTPS protocol?

Comment: There is more to HTTPS than just one single request so it might be difficult to explain it in a comment, sorry for pasting links but here you can lookup sslv3 sniffing: https://medium.com/devops-world/http-https-analysis-using-wireshark-cbe07c23520 (it's not marked as https in wireshark). Without access to the private key you won't be able to sniff the packet though.

Comment: @leebongee please accept the answer ;) thanks, I am collecting rep for bounties